# Ошибка при попытке кинуть запрос в Postman

Tags: node.js, express

Поднимаю локально сервис и пытаюсь прокинуть POST запрос по руту:

```
public routes() {
this.router.route('/register/user-profile/new').post(registerMiddleware, this.authService.register);
}
```

Сама функция регистрации в сервисе:

```
public async register(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      const { passportId, firstName, lastName, surName, mobilePhone } = req.body;

      const checkPassport = await getRepository(Passport).findOne({ passportId });

      if (checkPassport) {
        return res.status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: 'Passport with this code is already registered' });
      }

      await getRepository(Passport).save({ passportId });

      const client = await getRepository(Client).save({
        mobilePhone,
        firstName,
        surName,
        lastName,
        clientStatus: ClientStatus.NOT_ACTIVE,
        passportId,
      });

      await getRepository(UserProfile).save({ clientId: client.clientId });

      return res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json({ msg: 'Register successfull', client });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ msg: error.message });
    }
  }
```

Ловлю такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в консоли есть ошибки?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin в консоли ошибок нет, мне логи нужно написать, верно?

Comment: да. ошибка из postman мало что говорит)